# Compare Strings

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, complexity

> You have been given two strings, A and B (of length N each) and Q
>   queries. The strings contain only 0s and/or 1s.
>
> For every query, you are given an index i. You have to update the
>   value at index i to 1 in string B and check if B is lexicographically
>   equal to or larger than A or not. If yes, then print "YES" and if not,
>   print "NO" (without quotes).
>
> Input format
>
> ```
> First line contains two space-separated integers N and Q.
> Next line contains the string A.
> Next line contains the string B.
> Next Q lines contains an integer i (1 - based indexing)
> ```
>
> Output Format
>
> For each query, print the desired output in a new line.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 5 5
> 11111
> 00010
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> NO
> NO
> NO
> NO
> YES
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> ```
> After 1st query: B = 10010. B < A. (NO)
> After 2nd query: B = 11010. B < A. (NO)
> After 3rd query: B = 11110. B < A. (NO)
> After 4th query: B = 11110. B < A. (NO)
> After 5th query: B = 11111. B = A. (YES)
> ```

My solution in Python:

```py
# Write your code here
N_Q = list(map(int, input().split()))

string_a_list = list(input())
string_b_list = list(input())
different_set = set()
for index in range(N_Q[0]):
    if string_a_list[index] != string_b_list[index]:
        different_set.add(index + 1)

for query in range(N_Q[1]):
    index_q = int(input()) # 1 based
    index = index_q - 1
    string_b_list[index] = 1
    if len(different_set) == 0:
        break
    if int(string_a_list[index]) == int(string_b_list[index]):
        different_set.discard(index_q)
    if len(different_set) != 0:
        print("NO")


if len(different_set) == 0:
    print("YES")
if len(different_set) > 0:
    firstIndex = next(iter(different_set))
    index == firstIndex - 1
    if int(string_a_list[index]) > int(string_b_list[index]):
        print("NO")
    if int(string_a_list[index]) < int(string_b_list[index]):
        print("YES")
```

But for one test case that has got really very large input it's taking 5 sec so I'm getting timeout for that case:

[Submission](https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/16830564/)

```
Input #8    5.001169    22512    0
```

How can I optimize this further? What are the critical points to solve problem like this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can
 - List item
 - just use list comparison, so no need to convert between int and str
 - make `a` and `b` lists of 1s and 0s
 - make the diff-set with a set comparison
 - keep a flag. Once `b` is larger than or equal to `a`, it will stay this way

My code:

```
N, Q = list(map(int, input().split()))

a = list(map(int, input()))
b = list(map(int, input()))
diff = {i
    for i, (j, k) in enumerate(zip(a, b))
    if j != k
}

smaller = a > b
for _ in range(Q):
    idx = int(input()) - 1
    if smaller and idx in diff:
        b[idx] = 1
        diff.remove(idx)    
        if smaller and a > b :
            print('NO')
        else:
            print('YES')
            smaller = True
    else:
        if smaller:
            print('NO')
        else:
            print('YES')
            smaller = False
```

## Alternative solution

What really matters is at what index the first element of `A` is larger than `B` and vice versa, so we just keep track of those, and only set `B[idx]` to 1 in :

```
N, Q = list(map(int, input().split()))

A = list(map(int, input()))
B = list(map(int, input()))

idx_a = None
idx_b = len(B)
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(A, B)):
    if a > b and idx_a is None:
        idx_a = i
    if idx_a is not None and b > a:
        idx_b = i
        break
a_larger = True
if idx_a is None:
    a_larger = False

for _ in range(Q):
    idx = int(input()) - 1
    if not a_larger: 
        print('YES')
        continue
    elif idx < idx_a:
        if not B[idx]:
            print('YES')
            a_larger = False
        else:
            print('NO')
        continue
    elif idx == idx_a:
        B[idx] = 1
        idx_a = find_new_a_idx(A, B, idx_a, idx_b)
        if idx_a is None:
            print('YES')
            a_larger = False
        else:
            print('NO')
        continue
    print('NO')
    if idx >= idx_b:
        continue
        if not B[idx]:
            B[idx] = 1
            if not A[idx]:
                idx_b = idx
```

This is rather ugly code to take all the edge cases into account.

I tried also with `array.array('b)'`, but that was not faster

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to keep a track of lexicographical ordering for every pair of suffixes. Then for every update just update the ordering for suffix starting from index `i`. If ordering was changed then update suffix starting from `i-1` and keep on updating as long as there are changes. The current state after every query can be found from `suffix[0]`.

```
n, q = (int(x) for x in input().split())
a = [int(x) for x in input()]
b = [int(x) for x in input()]

def update(idx):
    for i in range(idx, -1, -1):
        x = b[i] - a[i]
        if x == 0 and i < n - 1:
            x = suffix[i + 1]
        if x == suffix[i]:
            break
        suffix[i] = x

# Initialize to invalid value to force initial update
suffix = [-2] * n
update(n - 1)

# Buffer results for faster output
res = []
for _ in range(q):
    i = int(input()) - 1
    b[i] = 1
    update(i)
    res.append('YES' if suffix[0] >= 0 else 'NO')

print('\n'.join(res))
```

Since every index can be updated maximum 2 times the time complexity is **O(N + Q)**.